# Lua JSON unexpected type `function`

Tags: json, lua, lua-table

I have following code for DCS:World scripting:

```
koUDPSocket = {}

koUDPSocket.host = "127.0.0.1"
--koTCPSocket.host = "85.221.224.254"
koUDPSocket.port = 52525
koUDPSocket.socket = socket.udp()
koUDPSocket.JSON = require "JSON"

function koUDPSocket:send(data, typee)
    local message = {
        typee = typee,
        data = data,
    }
    env.info("SENDING:")
    env.info(koEngine.TableSerialization(message))
    local jsonString = self.JSON:encode(message).." \n"

    socket.try(self.socket:sendto(jsonString, self.host, self.port))
    env.info("UDP DATA SENT")
 end
 


function countUnitsInTable(table)
    local count = 0
    for _, _ in pairs(table) do
        count = count + 1
    end
    return count
end

function koEngine.loadMissionDataShort()

    --debugee.pool()
    koEngine.debugText("koEngine.loadMissionDataShort")
    koEngine.debugText("loading shorted mission data")

    for categoryName, categoryTable in pairs(MissionData) do
        if type(categoryTable) == "table" and categoryName ~= "properties" then
            for objectiveName, objectiveTable in pairs(categoryTable) do
                if type(objectiveTable) == "table" then
                    local unitCount = 0
                    if objectiveTable.groups then
                        for _, group in pairs(objectiveTable.groups) do
                            if group.units then
                                unitCount = unitCount + countUnitsInTable(group.units)
                            end
                        end
                    end

                    local shortData = {
                        underAttack = objectiveTable.underAttack,
                        coa = objectiveTable.coa,
                        status = objectiveTable.status,
                        priority = objectiveTable.priority,
                        type = categoryName,
                        units = unitCount
                    }
                    missionDataShort[objectiveName] = shortData
                    koEngine.debugText("insert: " .. tostring(objectiveName))
                end
            end
        end
    end

    -- now send the data
    koUDPSocket:send(missionDataShort, "MissionDataShort")

    koEngine.debugText("END populating short data")
end
```

which gets all objectives from mission data, puts in table, and attempts to send to my Node.JS server to process further. Everything works, expect line with
`local jsonString = self.JSON:encode(message).." \n"`
which gives error "unecptected type: `function`"

interesting is that trying `type(message)` gives `table`, and not `function`

how can I determine where the real mistake is? And how can I debug data to really see if it's a function? What's the best way to do it?

Here is a fragment of data, outputted using env.info(koEngine.TableSerialization(message)) and previous line:

```
2023-08-23 19:27:44.840 INFO    SCRIPTING (Main): SENDING:
2023-08-23 19:27:44.848 INFO    SCRIPTING (Main): {
    ['data'] = {
        ['FARP Oche'] = {
            ['type'] = 'FARP',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 0,
            ['coa'] = 'neutral',
        },
        ['Antenna Bulls'] = {
            ['type'] = 'Communication',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 0,
            ['coa'] = 'neutral',
        },
        ['FARP Tsvirmi'] = {
            ['type'] = 'FARP',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 0,
            ['coa'] = 'neutral',
        },
        ['Sukhumi-Babushara'] = {
            ['type'] = 'Aerodrome',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'open',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 27,
            ['coa'] = 'blue',
        },
        ['FARP Lentehi'] = {
            ['type'] = 'FARP',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 0,
            ['coa'] = 'neutral',
        },
        ['Antenna Balkariya'] = {
            ['type'] = 'Communication',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 3,
            ['coa'] = 'red',
        },
        ['Antenna Oche'] = {
            ['type'] = 'Communication',
            ['underAttack'] = false,
            ['status'] = 'closed',
            ['priority'] = 'strategic',
            ['units'] = 0,
            ['coa'] = 'neutral',
        },
```

I wrote a code, I tested a possible problem, which it wasn't, and now I want to investigate further

Comment: Where did you initialize `missionDataShort` variable?  It looks as it is a global variable already containing some content (including a function somewhere) - is it an object of some class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

idk I solved this, problem was with self.JSON:encode. Changed to JSON.encode, and worked

Comment: Indeed, you should write `self.JSON.encode(message)` instead of `self.JSON:encode(message)`